# How to say, someone is less (adj) than someone else?

Tags: mandarin

How do I say,

He is less cool than I?

Answer (score 5):

没有 + 那么 + what you want to compare

• He is less cool than I

他 没有 我 那么 酷

• I'm not that cool

我没有那么酷

• I'm not as cool as him

我没有他那么酷

Answer (score 1):

不如 [not up to;inferior to] 表示前面提到的人或事物比不上后面所说的

他不如我酷.

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/view/2248882.htm